# Facebook Like Box breaks in reaload with Rails Website

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, html, facebook

I have a facebook plugin like this

[image]

When i access the page, this works properly, but when I click in a link to home, it happens

[image]

By some reason, it only works with reload, not with click homepage link. Does anyone had this problem?

Fb code (application.html.erb)

```html
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.10";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Code on home view:

```html
 <div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/sindbertioga" data-tabs="timeline" data-height="400" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/sindbertioga" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/sindbertioga">Sindicato Dos Servidores Públicos Municipais de Bertioga</a></blockquote></div>
```

Comment: You're likely using turbolinks, which means you are not actually loading new pages, but replacing DOM contents via JavaScript, so you need to call the SDK's parse method after new elements to be parsed into social plugins have been inserted. http://reed.github.io/turbolinks-compatibility/facebook.html

Comment: can you check if you are indeed using turbolinks? if so you can wrap your fb script with the appropriate turbolink event so that it loads properly